# upgrading to Goland 2021.2 "No problem found" tons of RED files

Tags: goland

I have tons of an IDE errors, where the file is red - even there is "No problems found" in the files.

Update: I realised I had moved some files around just before upgrading. And as the right answer states it, the red files are unversioned under Git(see answer from artspb)

[image]

[image]

This happened after upgrading to Goland 2021.2 - MacOS Big Sur

I tried to "Invalidate caches..." under files.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you use Go modules? If yes, is integrating enabled under Settings | Go | Go modules?

Comment: Thanks - Yes I am using modules, and "Enable Go modules intergration" is checked.

Comment: I see. Do you have red import statements? Is there Sync dependencies when you hit Alt+Enter on them? Does it help running synchronization?

Comment: No red import statement, and I can navigate to each import. What is Sync dependencies?

Comment: All modules is downloaded if that is Synched dep.

Comment: It's a fix to let the IDE know about dependencies. But if there are no red imports, it shouldn't appear. Let's start from the beginning then. What kind of errors do you see? What do you mean be "the file is red?" It'd be great to see a screenshot. You might find it more convenient to continue over email. Just drop us a message via Help | Contact Support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235754/discussion-between-chris-g-and-artspb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red files are unversioned under Git, the green files are staged, and so on (see [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/file-status-highlights.html)).